# New Team Foundation Server 2010 Installation

Tags: team-foundation-server, windows

Before starting down the TFS2010 installation process, I have a few questions I'm hoping the community can help me with.

We're planning on a single-server installation of TFS2010.  Initially, we want version/source control and build services, but not reporting or SharePoint.  We may add reporting and SharePoint capabilities later.  Our environment will be Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64), SQL Server 2008 R2 (x64), Office 2010 (x86), Visual Studio 6 and 2010, and, of course, Team Foundation Server 2010.

- Can I install TFS2010 on a server
  that is on our domain?  It's not a
  domain controller, it's just a member
  server on the domain.
- Should I install TFS2010 before or
  after putting the server on the
  domain? We have six developers that
  will be logging into their local
  development computers (which are also
  on the same domain) using their
  domain user accounts, do I add each
  domain user to the TFS2010 server's
  security groups?  If so, which
  one(s)?
- Can I or should I use a domain user
  account as the TFS2010 service
  account?  Or, should I just use
  Network Service?
- The TFS2010 install guide notes that
  none of the service accounts should
  belong to the Administrators security
  group, so which security group(s) are
  recommended for the service
  account(s)?
- We're planning on using a local
  instance of SQL Server 2008 R2
  Standard with TFS2010, what service
  account should we use?  Should we use
  the same domain account as TFS2010 or
  Local System or ??  The TFS2010
  install guide isn't very specific on
  this.
- Since we're planning on this server
  being both the version/source control
  and build server, should we install
  our development environments (VS6,
  VS2010, Access2010) before installing
  TFS2010?  Or does it matter?

Thanks in advance for answering these questions.

---

Thanks again Ewald for the information.  I have a couple of clarification questions, if you don't mind.

In the TFS2010 installation guide, it notes for the Team Foundation Server component:

- You must not use the account that you
  use to install Team Foundation Server
  as the account for TFSSERVICE. For
  example, if you are logged in as
  domain\user1 when you install Team
  Foundation Server, do not use
  domain\user1 as the account for
  TFSSERVICE.

I have my domain user account that will be in the local Administrators group on the server, so I guess what this is saying is that I need our IT department to create me another domain user account to use as the TFS service account, is this correct?

Also in the TFS2010 installation guide, it notes for Best Practices for Accounts:

- None of the accounts in this topic
  should belong to the Administrators
  security group.

So, if I have another domain user account that I'll be using for the TFS service account, into which local groups should I put this new domain user account?  Just in Users?  Or Power Users?  Or???

Finally, who should I be logged into the server as when I run the installation?  Local Administrator?  My domain user that will be in the Administrators group?  Or?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes you can install TFS on any server in your domain.
- First put your server in the domain and then install TFS. You need service accounts during the installation, while you could use local accounts it is recommended to use domain service accounts. Especially when you use build (which needs access to drop folders)
- Put one or two key users in the Project Administrators group. The rest of your users (or an active directory group) add them to the Contributors group
- I always use a domain user account. Network Service might also do the job - just never did it.
- You don't have to add the service account manually. When you follow the wizard it is all done for you.
- You can run SQL Server with the LocalSystem account
- When you install the build services, MSBuild is installed. MSBuild can compile C# and VB.NET. Some tasks of the build - like Code Analysis, Unit Tests, Coded UI Tests [thanks to Ryan] - require the installation of VS2010. To compile VB6 or MSAcccess, you need to install those tools.

Comment: Things like Code Analysis, Unit Tests, Coded UI Tests require VS on the build server.

Comment: I'm new to the StackOverflow site, so I'm not sure how to ask you additional questions, so I'll just use the Answer Your Question option (even though I'm not really answering anything).